# Monitoring prime factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

$$(p_1 \times p_2 \times \cdots \times p_n) + 1 = (q_1 \times q_2 \times \cdots \times q_m)$$
Where $p_1 \cdots p_n$ and $q_1 \cdots q_m$ are prime factors for two numbers $x$ and $y$ in the equation $x+1=y$. For example: $$99+1=100$$ or $$ (3 \times 3 \times 11) +1 = (2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 5)$$
As in the example above: $3 \times 3 \times 11$ (which are the prime factors of $99$) changes completely into $2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 5$ (which are the prime factors of $100$) after adding $1$.

So I was wondering if there is a way to find out the prime factors of $y$ when you have the prime factors of $x$, or simply a way to monitor the change in the prime factors of both numbers.

Comment: Usually no: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers : the only factor of $(F_n - 1)=(2^{2^n})$ is $2$, but that is huge problem to determine factors of $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ (for $n=20$, $n=24$ etc). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cullen_number too.

Comment: @Oleg567, sorry that's not what i meant. I edited the question, check it now. I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: The only obvious relationship based on adding $1$ (as opposed to adding some arbitrary number $k$) is that one of the two numbers must have $2$ among its prime factors, and the other must not.

Comment: @KeithBackman , actually that's true only if $k$ is odd, however I need something general.

Comment: Isn't the edit running exactly in the issue Oleg567 posted. For $x=2^{2^n}$ we know all the prime factors, yet we don't know anything about the prime factors of $y=x+1$.

Comment: we do, but it doesn't tell us what they are. @N.S.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if number theory had the power to induce a full factorization at each step (without trial division etc.), we could do away with caring about factorization and induce the first $10^{200}$ factorizations with enough time.

That being said we know a few things:

- Factors will never be shared amongst adjacent numbers.
- Testing the next number for divisibility by prime $r$, is as simple as showing $za\equiv-1\pmod r$,  $a$ the additive inverse mod $r$ of $-a$ and $z$ the multiplicative inverse mod $r$ , holds for some subset of the factors clumped together. This of course is non-trivial to test for with a large number of prime factors counted with multiplicities.
- prime factors can be arbitrarily large as $y$ grows.

  This and a few other things, start to make inducing factorization not so useful or practical.

Comment: Replying to each point independently: 1) how didn't I think about that ?!    2)okaaaay     3)of course it can     conclusion: If you have any other thing that you'd like to mention please write it and also if you have a link to a webpage which can help post it please, and thanks for your help :)

Comment: for example of 2) $3\cdot (3\cdot 1)\equiv 4\pmod 5$ implies the next number after 99 is divisible by 5, because the multiplication of its factors remainders, gives us back a remainder of 4 ( aka -1).

Comment: First this can be useful in some cases, second this isn't a solution, third I thought there is a formula or a whole branch for something like that, fourth you mentioned a good point but I can't use that on unknowns, can I ?

Comment: If you know a full factorization you can, even parital is possible, but it won't fully factorize each number , it's nearly as close as you'll get in practice. $99=3\cdot 33\equiv 3\cdot 3\equiv 4$ still tells you that 100 is divisible by 5, and likewise you can show by 4, and by 25 as the rule is actually a general rule, for use when they both exist.

Comment: I suppose I have to show my hidden card: this question is all about collatz conjecture, I thought "$3n+1$ when $n$ is odd, this means that $n$ can be factorized into prime factors which doesn't include $2$ and after adding $1$ TADA we have a $2$" so I thought that collatz conjecture has something to do with prime factors.

Comment: it does, as we know the odds that each $3n+1$ produces( aka $6k+4$) go connect to odds that don't share factors.

Comment: I didn't know that, if this has a proof on a webpage or a website can you please share it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101343/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-anas-khaled).